# Capturing whole word and not partial words in php mySQL database search query

Tags: php, mysql, search, cpu-word

beginner here, I am writing a PHP search program that will look for keywords in a MySQL database.  How do I capture whole words only and not partial words (e.g.just man and not wo"man").

```
//construct query

$x++;

    if ($x==1)

        $construct = "keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

    else

        $construct = "keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
```

thanks for your help

Comment: simple: `keywords='man'`

Answer (score 0):

Use delimiters.  Assuming they are separated by spaces:

```
$construct = "concat(' ', keywords, ' ') LIKE '% $search_each %'";
```

If they are separated by commas, you can use:

```
$construct = "find_in_set($search_each, keywords) > 0";
```

Neither of these have particularly good performance, because they require a full table scan.

You should have a separate table with one row per entity id/keyword.  Don't store keywords in a list in a single column!

Comment: @Dagon Personally, I wouldn't know. Programming used 9" floppy disks at the time. I doubt that term even existed, way back when ;-)

Comment: well we used stone tablets, and chisels ... :-)

Comment: @Dagon And they still exist to this very day! ;-) Just goes to show, that they don't make 'em like they used to. (stone tablets that is) and the tablets have changed in thickness and weight too.

Comment: using a chisel on a modern tablet voids the warranty- but sure is satisfying! ;)

Comment: Too funny (Literally LMHO) @Dagon Good one ;-) I'll remember that, the next time one ticks me off. (Local cafés, beware)

Comment: thank you for your solution @Fred -ii-. that solved my problem. I am also looking for an a way to search for two or more keywords exclusive to one file (e.g. search for "blue dress" where it pulls files that only contain both terms not one or the other: "blue" or "dress") Any help is greatly appreciated.